# Macro that automatically runs in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have two tables in the first spreadsheet of my workbook called SOW. Every cell in both tables are linked to tables in the following two spreadsheets (Services and Third-Party respectively). Data entered into the table in the second spreadsheet (the Services tab) populates the first table in the SOW tab. Data entered into the table in the third spreadsheet (Third-Party tab) is populated in the second table in the SOW tab. I need to make it so that rows in the SOW tables are only visible if there is data entered into one of the two corresponding tables in the following two tabs. If there isn't any data in the tables of the second and third tabs, then the corresponding rows in the SOW tables need to be hidden.

The macro I wrote below (this code is only for one of the two tables, the macros for the second table is equally as long) works when assigned to a button but doesn't seem to work automatically on its own even after trying with a worksheet_change sub. Is there a way to write a macro that will automatically always run without a user needing to press a macro button or clicking run? If this is possible, what is the best way to do so without drastically slowing down the overall speed of the workbook. While I did try entering the codes below into a worksheet_change sub, this is from the macro I used for buttons after the worksheet_change attempt failed.

```
Sub SOWServicesEmptyCells()
Call TurnOffFunctions
'1st Section
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B28") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("28:48").Hidden = True
    End If
'1A
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C29") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("29").Hidden = True
End If
'1B
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C30") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("30").Hidden = True
End If
'1C
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C31") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("31").Hidden = True
End If
'1D
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C32") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("32").Hidden = True
End If
'1E
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C33") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("33").Hidden = True
End If
'1F
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C34") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("34").Hidden = True
End If
'1G
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C34") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("34").Hidden = True
End If
'1H
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C35") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("35").Hidden = True
End If
'1I
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C36") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("36").Hidden = True
End If
'1J
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C37") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("37").Hidden = True
End If
'1K
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C38") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("38").Hidden = True
End If
'1L
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C39") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("39").Hidden = True
End If
'1M
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C40") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("40").Hidden = True
End If
'1N
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C41") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("41").Hidden = True
End If
'1O
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C42") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("42").Hidden = True
End If
'1P
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C43") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("43").Hidden = True
End If
'1Q
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C44") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("44").Hidden = True
End If
'1R
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C45") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("45").Hidden = True
End If
'1S
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C46") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("46").Hidden = True
End If
'1T
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C47") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("47").Hidden = True
End If
'1U
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C48") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("48").Hidden = True
End If
'Second Section
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B49") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("49:69").Hidden = True
 End If
'2A
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C50") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("50").Hidden = True
 End If
'2B
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C51") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("51").Hidden = True
 End If
'2C
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C52") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("52").Hidden = True
 End If
'2D
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C53") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("53").Hidden = True
 End If
'2E
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C54") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("54").Hidden = True
 End If
'2F
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C55") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("55").Hidden = True
 End If
'2G
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C56") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("56").Hidden = True
 End If
'2H
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C57") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("57").Hidden = True
 End If
'2I
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C58") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("58").Hidden = True
 End If
'2J
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C59") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("59").Hidden = True
 End If
'2K
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C60") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("60").Hidden = True
 End If
'2L
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C61") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("61").Hidden = True
 End If
'2M
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C62") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("62").Hidden = True
 End If
'2N
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C63") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("63").Hidden = True
 End If
'2O
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C64") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("64").Hidden = True
 End If
'2P
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C65") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("65").Hidden = True
 End If
'2Q
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C66") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("66").Hidden = True
 End If
'2R
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C67") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("67").Hidden = True
 End If
'2S
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C68") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("68").Hidden = True
 End If
'2T
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C69") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("69").Hidden = True
 End If
'3rd Section
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B70") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("70:90").Hidden = True
End If
'3A
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C71") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("71").Hidden = True
End If
'3B
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C72") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("72").Hidden = True
End If
'3C
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C73") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("73").Hidden = True
End If
'3D
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C74") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("74").Hidden = True
End If
'3E
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C75") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("75").Hidden = True
End If
'3F
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C76") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("76").Hidden = True
End If
'3G
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C77") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("77").Hidden = True
End If
'3H
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C78") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("78").Hidden = True
End If
'3I
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C79") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("79").Hidden = True
End If
'3J
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C80") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("80").Hidden = True
'3K
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C81") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("81").Hidden = True
End If
'3L
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C82") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("82").Hidden = True
End If
'3M
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C83") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("83").Hidden = True
End If
'3N
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C84") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("85").Hidden = True
End If
'3O
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C86") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("86").Hidden = True
End If
'3P
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C87") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("87").Hidden = True
End If
'3Q
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C88") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("88").Hidden = True
End If
'3R
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C89") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("89").Hidden = True
End If
'3S
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C90") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("90").Hidden = True
End If
'4th Section
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B91") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("91:111").Hidden = True
End If
'4A
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B92") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("92").Hidden = True
End If
'4B
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B93") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("93").Hidden = True
End If
'4C
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B94") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("94").Hidden = True
End If
'4D
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B95") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("95").Hidden = True
End If
'4E
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B96") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("96").Hidden = True
End If
'4F
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B97") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("97").Hidden = True
End If
'4G
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B98") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("98").Hidden = True
End If
'4H
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B99") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("99").Hidden = True
End If
'4I
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B100") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("100").Hidden = True
End If
'4J
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B101") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("101").Hidden = True
End If
'4K
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B102") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("102").Hidden = True
End If
'4L
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B103") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("103").Hidden = True
End If
'4M
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B104") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("104").Hidden = True
End If
'4N
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B105") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("105").Hidden = True
End If
'4O
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B106") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("106").Hidden = True
End If
'4P
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B107") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("107").Hidden = True
End If
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C108") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("108").Hidden = True
 End If
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C109") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("109").Hidden = True
 End If
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C110") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("110").Hidden = True
 End If
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C111") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("111").Hidden = True
 End If
'5th Section
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B112") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("112:132").Hidden = True
End If
'5A
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B113") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("113").Hidden = True
End If
'5B
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B114") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("114").Hidden = True
End If
'5C
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B115") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("115").Hidden = True
End If
'5D
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B116") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("116").Hidden = True
End If
'5E
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B117") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("117").Hidden = True
End If
'5F
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B118") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("118").Hidden = True
End If
'5G
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B119") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("119").Hidden = True
End If
'5H
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B120") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("120").Hidden = True
End If
'5J
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B120") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("120").Hidden = True
End If
'5K
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B120") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("120").Hidden = True
End If
'5L
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B121") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("121").Hidden = True
End If
'5M
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B122") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("122").Hidden = True
End If
'5N
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B123") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("123").Hidden = True
End If
'5O
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B124") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("124").Hidden = True
End If
'5P
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B125") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("125").Hidden = True
End If
'5Q
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B126") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("126").Hidden = True
End If
'5R
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B127") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("127").Hidden = True
End If
'5S
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B128") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("128").Hidden = True
End If
'5T
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B129") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("129").Hidden = True
End If
'5U
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B130") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("130").Hidden = True
End If
'5V
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B131") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("131").Hidden = True
End If
'SX
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B132") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("132").Hidden = True
End If
'6th Section
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B133") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("133:153").Hidden = True
End If
'6A
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B134") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("134").Hidden = True
End If
'6B
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B135") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("135").Hidden = True
End If
'6C
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B136") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("136").Hidden = True
End If
'6D
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B137") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("137").Hidden = True
End If
'6E
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B138") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("138").Hidden = True
End If
'6F
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B139") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("139").Hidden = True
End If
'6G
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B140") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("140").Hidden = True
End If
'6H
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B141") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("141").Hidden = True
End If
'6I
 If Sheets("SOW").Range("B142") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("142").Hidden = True
End If
'6J
 If Sheets("SOW").Range("B143") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("143").Hidden = True
End If
'6K
 If Sheets("SOW").Range("B144") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("144").Hidden = True
End If
'6L
 If Sheets("SOW").Range("B145") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("145").Hidden = True
End If
'6M
 If Sheets("SOW").Range("B146") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("146").Hidden = True
End If
'6N
 If Sheets("SOW").Range("B147") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("147").Hidden = True
End If
'6O
 If Sheets("SOW").Range("B148") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("148").Hidden = True
End If
'6P
 If Sheets("SOW").Range("B149") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("149").Hidden = True
End If
'6Q
 If Sheets("SOW").Range("B150") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("150").Hidden = True
End If
'6R
 If Sheets("SOW").Range("B151") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("151").Hidden = True
End If
'6S
 If Sheets("SOW").Range("B152") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("152").Hidden = True
End If
'6T
 If Sheets("SOW").Range("B153") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("153").Hidden = True
End If
'7th Section
 If Sheets("SOW").Range("B154") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("154:174").Hidden = True
End If
'7A
 If Sheets("SOW").Range("B155") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("155").Hidden = True
End If
'7B
 If Sheets("SOW").Range("B156") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("156").Hidden = True
End If
'7C
 If Sheets("SOW").Range("B157") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("157").Hidden = True
End If
'7D
 If Sheets("SOW").Range("B158") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("158").Hidden = True
End If
'7E
 If Sheets("SOW").Range("B159") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("159").Hidden = True
End If
'7F
 If Sheets("SOW").Range("B160") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("160").Hidden = True
End If
'7G
 If Sheets("SOW").Range("B161") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("161").Hidden = True
End If
'7H
 If Sheets("SOW").Range("B162") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("162").Hidden = True
End If
'7I
 If Sheets("SOW").Range("B163") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("163").Hidden = True
End If
'7J
 If Sheets("SOW").Range("B164") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("164").Hidden = True
End If
'7K
 If Sheets("SOW").Range("B165") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("165").Hidden = True
End If
'7L
 If Sheets("SOW").Range("B166") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("166").Hidden = True
End If
'7M
 If Sheets("SOW").Range("B167") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("167").Hidden = True
End If
'7N
 If Sheets("SOW").Range("B168") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("168").Hidden = True
End If
'7O
 If Sheets("SOW").Range("B169") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("169").Hidden = True
End If
'7P
 If Sheets("SOW").Range("B170") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("170").Hidden = True
End If
'7Q
 If Sheets("SOW").Range("B171") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("171").Hidden = True
End If
'7R
 If Sheets("SOW").Range("B172") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("172").Hidden = True
End If
'7S
 If Sheets("SOW").Range("B173") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("173").Hidden = True
End If
'7T
 If Sheets("SOW").Range("B174") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("174").Hidden = True
End If
'8th Section
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B175") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("175:195").Hidden = True
End If
'8A
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B176") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("176").Hidden = True
End If
'8B
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B177") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("177").Hidden = True
End If
'8C
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B178") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("178").Hidden = True
End If
'8D
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B179") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("179").Hidden = True
End If
'8E
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B180") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("180").Hidden = True
End If
'8F
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B181") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("181").Hidden = True
End If
'8G
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B182") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("182").Hidden = True
End If
'8H
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B183") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("183").Hidden = True
End If
'8I
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B184") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("184").Hidden = True
End If
'8J
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B185") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("185").Hidden = True
End If
'8K
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B186") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("186").Hidden = True
End If
'8L
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B187") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("187").Hidden = True
End If
'8M
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B188") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("188").Hidden = True
End If
'8N
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B189") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("189").Hidden = True
End If
'8O
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B190") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("190").Hidden = True
End If
'8P
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B191") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("191").Hidden = True
End If
'8Q
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B192") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("192").Hidden = True
End If
'8R
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B193") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("193").Hidden = True
End If
'8S
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B194") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("194").Hidden = True
End If
'8T
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B195") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("195").Hidden = True
End If
'9th Section
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B196") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("196:216").Hidden = True
End If
'9A
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B197") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("197").Hidden = True
End If
'9B
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B198") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("198").Hidden = True
End If
'9C
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B199") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("199").Hidden = True
End If
'9D
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B200") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("200").Hidden = True
End If
'9E
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B201") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("201").Hidden = True
End If
'9F
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B202") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("202").Hidden = True
End If
'9G
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B203") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("203").Hidden = True
End If
'9H
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B204") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("204").Hidden = True
End If
'9I
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B205") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("205").Hidden = True
End If
'9J
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B206") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("206").Hidden = True
End If
'9K
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B207") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("207").Hidden = True
End If
'9L
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B208") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("208").Hidden = True
End If
'9M
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B209") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("209").Hidden = True
End If
'9N
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B210") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("210").Hidden = True
End If
'9O
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B211") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("211").Hidden = True
End If
'9P
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B212") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("212").Hidden = True
End If
'9Q
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B213") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("213").Hidden = True
End If
'9R
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B214") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("214").Hidden = True
End If
'9S
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B215") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("215").Hidden = True
End If
'9T
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B216") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("216").Hidden = True
End If
'10th Section
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B217") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("217:237").Hidden = True
End If
'10A
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B218") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("218").Hidden = True
End If
'10B
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B219") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("219").Hidden = True
End If
'10C
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B220") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("220").Hidden = True
End If
'10D
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B221") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("221").Hidden = True
End If
'10E
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B222") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("222").Hidden = True
End If
'10F
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B223") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("223").Hidden = True
End If
'10G
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B224") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("224").Hidden = True
End If
'10H
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B225") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("225").Hidden = True
End If
'10I
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B226") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("226").Hidden = True
End If
'10J
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B227") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("227").Hidden = True
End If
'10K
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B228") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("228").Hidden = True
End If
'10L
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B229") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("229").Hidden = True
End If
'10M
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B230") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("230").Hidden = True
End If
'10N
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B231") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("231").Hidden = True
End If
'10O
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B232") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("232").Hidden = True
End If
'10P
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B233") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("233").Hidden = True
End If
'10Q
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B234") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("234").Hidden = True
End If
'10R
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B235") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("234").Hidden = True
End If
'10S
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B235") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("234").Hidden = True
End If
'10T
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B236") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("236").Hidden = True
End If
'10U
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B237") = 0 Then
     Worksheets("SOW").Rows("237").Hidden = True
End If

Call TurnOnNotifications
End Sub
```

The codes above work, just not in the manner that I would like. I need to figure out a way to have these codes run automatically, as quickly together as possible without dramatically slowing down the workbook.

Comment: Does the data on the "SOW" tab get populated by formulas? Because `Worksheet_Change` will not work when when a formula recalculates. You'll need `Worksheet_Calculate` for that scenario.

Comment: Also - all those repetitive lines are just begging for a loop.

Comment: @BigBen I almost wanna just post up a revised code as that also hurt my eyes... yikes.

Comment: Hey @BigBen. Haha yeah I figured the macro could be done better but I'm new to using them. The Data on the "SOW" tab does get populated by formulas. Each cell in each SOW table is linked to the corresponding cell in the table in the Services tab and Third-Party tab respectively.

Comment: Right, so as mentioned you need to use `Worksheet_Calculate`.

Answer (score 0):

To make it faster you should …

1. Collect all rows to hide in a range variable, so you can hide them all at once in the end.
2. I highly recommend to use loops instead of repeating code over and over.
3. If a whole section was already hidden you can skip testing each row in that section.

I suggest the following:

```
Public Sub SOWServicesEmptyCells()
    'define constants
    Const SectionSize As Long = 20      'how big are your sections
    Const SectionCount As Long = 10     'how many sections do you have
    Const SectionStartRow As Long = 28  'in which row does the first section start

    Dim SectionLastRow As Long          'in which row does the last section end (we can calculate that)
    SectionLastRow = SectionStartRow - 1 + (SectionCount * (SectionSize + 1))

    Call TurnOffFunctions 'you probably don't need this anymore (should not have any effect on speed)

    Dim wsSOW As Worksheet
    Set wsSOW = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SOW") 'define your worksheet

    Dim RangeToHide As Range 'this is where we collect all rows that we want to hide

    'check and collect all rows to hide
    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = SectionStartRow To SectionLastRow
        If (iRow - SectionStartRow) Mod (SectionSize + 1) = 0 Then
            'whole section
            If wsSOW.Cells(iRow, "B").Value = 0 Then
                AddToRange RangeToHide, wsSOW.Rows(iRow & ":" & iRow + SectionSize)
                iRow = iRow + SectionSize 'skip testing rows in this section if section is completely hidden
            End If
        Else
            'inside section
            If wsSOW.Cells(iRow, "C").Value = 0 Then
                AddToRange RangeToHide, wsSOW.Rows(iRow)
            End If
        End If
    Next iRow

    'hide all rows at once
    If Not RangeToHide Is Nothing Then
        RangeToHide.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

    Call TurnOnNotifications
End Sub

'Add a range to a variable
Public Sub AddToRange(ByRef RangeToAddTo As Range, ByVal AddRange As Range)
    If RangeToAddTo Is Nothing Then
        Set RangeToAddTo = AddRange
    Else
        Set RangeToAddTo = Application.Union(RangeToAddTo, AddRange)
    End If
End Sub
```

---

If the amount of sections and their size or start row are fixed you can keep them as constants, but if they change I recommend to change them into parameters for your procedure:

```
Public Sub SOWServicesEmptyCells(ByVal SectionSize As Long, ByVal SectionCount As Long, ByVal SectionStartRow As Long)
    'remove the `Const` lines 
    'rest of the code like above
End Sub
```

And then call this procedure like

```
Public Sub Test()
    SOWServicesEmptyCells(20, 10, 28) 
    'or
    SOWServicesEmptyCells(SectionSize:=20, SectionCount:=10, SectionStartRow:=28) 
End If
```

---

If you need to run it on different worksheets you can even change the sheet into a parameter:

```
Public Sub ServicesEmptyCells(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal SectionSize As Long, ByVal SectionCount As Long, ByVal SectionStartRow As Long)
    'remove the dim and set of `wsSOW`
    'and replace all `swSOW` with `ws`

'then call it like
ServicesEmptyCells(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SOW"), 20, 10, 28)
```